# Passing service as a parameter of controller function in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have controller, view and services in separate files of an Angular application. These files are:

**home.controller.js**

```
angular
    .module('loc8rApp')
    .controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);

function homeCtrl () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pageHeader = {
        title: 'Loc8r',
        strapline: 'Find places to work with wifi near you'
    };
}
```

**home.view.html**

```
<div id="banner" class="page-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <h1>
      {{ vm.pageHeader.title }}
      <small>{{ vm.pageHeader.strapline }}</small>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**loc8rData.service.js**

```
angular
    .module('loc8rApp')
    .service('loc8rData', loc8rData);

var loc8rData = function ($http) {
    var locationByCoords = function (lat, lng) {
        return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat + '&maxDistance=10000');
    };
    return {
        locationByCoords: locationByCoords
    };
};
```

The application with **home.controller.js** and **home.view.html** is ok. Now I want to use the service **loc8rData** which is defined in **loc8rData.service.js** file. To use the service from the controller, I passed the service name as a parameter of **homeCtrl** function. It then created an issue. It is showing angular expression instead of the value of that expression. The following image is the best fit to observe the issue:

[image: showing expression instead of value]

What is the reason behind it? What will be the proper solution?

Comment: show how you have injected the service

Comment: I have just included the service to the angular app which is the first statement of the loc8rData.service.js file. Is it enough?

Comment: You need to inject the service to controller

Comment: How to inject the service into a controller?
I've just passed the service name as a parameter to the controller function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your service to your controller as follows,

```
 homeCtrl.$inject = ['loc8rData'];
 function homeCtrl (loc8rData) {

 }
```

also change your service function as follows , make it globally accessible

```
angular
    .module('loc8rApp')
    .service('loc8rData', loc8rData);

function loc8rData($http) {
    var locationByCoords = function (lat, lng) {
        return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat + '&maxDistance=10000');
    };
    return {
        locationByCoords: locationByCoords
    };
};
```

Comment: In which place? Immediately before the controller function?

Comment: I have done this, but still it is showing expression :(

Comment: Yes, a lot actually